# How to fix Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, mysqli

Please, how do i fix this please. I have initially being using mysql with which i have issues. Now i have started learning mysqli. I don't know all the details now but i need to make this script work and secure. Currently i have this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\yomi\admin\update.php on line 27

**Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `brief` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `contents` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(2000) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE news SET title = ?,
   brief = ?,
   contents = ?, 
   author = ? 
   WHERE id = 1");

// set parameters and execute
$stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $_POST['title'],
$_POST['brief'],
$_POST['contents'],
$_POST['author'],
$_POST['id']);
$stmt->execute();
echo "New records updated successfully";
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Missing a `,` after `$_POST['author']`

Comment: add comma after $_POST['author'] like $_POST['author'],

Comment: should be like this   $stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $_POST['title'],
    $_POST['brief'],
    $_POST['contents'],
    $_POST['author'],
    $_POST['id']);

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is simple typographical error

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a comma after $_POST['author']

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $_POST['title'],
    $_POST['brief'],
    $_POST['contents'],
    $_POST['author'],
    $_POST['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "New records updated successfully";
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I still need help with this as i still get error after my typo you just pointed out.// prepare and bind
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE news SET title = ?,
   brief = ?,
   contents = ?, 
   author = ? 
   WHERE id = 3");

// set parameters and execute
$stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $_POST['title'],
$_POST['brief'],
$_POST['contents'],
$_POST['author'],
$_POST['3']);
$stmt->execute();
echo "New records updated successfully";
$conn->close();

Comment: it would help if you would tell us more about that new error. It could be because you have only 4 placeholders in the prepared statement and you want to insert 5 variables (your id is hardcoded as 1 (3 in the last comment) and still you want to bind $_POST['id'] into the statement. something is wrong there,,

Comment: Thanks again and again. This is the error 
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\yomi\admin\update.php on line 16. I guess my problem is 'id'. The issue is i dont know how to do this.

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\yomi\admin\update.php on line 16. The code related are the ones posted above. Your help is really appreciated

Comment: ah i see the problem. you have called the function prepare from a variable called $mysqli that does not exist in your context. you should replace $mysqli->prepare with $conn->prepare. I guess this problem occurred because you copy pasted from the manual of php.net but you didnt see that there, your variable $conn is called $mysqli.
But its unclear to me if you understood my last comment where i pointed out that you should replace the part of the query "WHERE id = 1" with "WHERE id = ?".
Please vote up my answer and accept it, for i am desperately needing that reputation. Ty and cheers

Comment: Thanks, your answer does not totally solve my problem but it get me far in my debugging process. Besides it is the only answer nearer to my solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma after `$_POST['author']` where you are binding your parameters.